# Cube and Rollup equivalent?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, olap

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to implement Cube and Rollup operators without using the predefined SQL operators? 
In other words, without using the group by Cube/Rollup (..)

Comment: You can use `grouping sets`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can I also use the Union operator grouping on different attributes? Could it be correct?

Comment: . . `UNION ALL`.  And yes, they would do the same thing if you listed out all the combinations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff one last question. I know that the Cube operator calculates all the possible combinations of the attributes in the group by clause. Can you tell me how the combinations in the rollup case are calculated? I mean, what are the combinations involved in the rollup operation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff for example if we have the table Sales(city, product_type, amount) and we use group by Rollup(city, product_type), what are the combinations calculated by the operator?

Comment: The postgres docs are usually (IMHO) a good place to go to understand many SQL concepts. The docs on grouping sets are no exception and may help here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS